# How to enable gzip for Apache 2.4?

Tags: javascript, apache, gzip

I created a configuration file for the gzip with help official documentation, but it doesn't works. I use Apache 2.4 version.

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
   <filesMatch "\.(js|html|css)$">
      SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
   </filesMatch>

   DeflateCompressionLevel 9

   # Accurate Logging
   DeflateFilterNote Input instream
   DeflateFilterNote Output outstream
   DeflateFilterNote Ratio ratio

   LogFormat '"%r" %{outstream}n/%{instream}n (%{ratio}n%%)' deflate
   CustomLog logs/deflate_log DEFLATE

   Header append Vary: User-Agent
</IfModule>
```

Also I try use a next config, but it didn't work either:

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
   # Force deflate for mangled headers
   <IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
      <IfModule mod_headers.c>
         SetEnvIfNoCase ^(Accept-EncodXng|X-cept-Encoding|X{15}|~{15}|-{15})$ ^((gzip|deflate)\s*,?\s*)+|[X~-]{4,13}$ HAVE_Accept-Encoding
         RequestHeader append Accept-Encoding "gzip,deflate" env=HAVE_Accept-Encoding
      </IfModule>
   </IfModule>
   <IfModule mod_filter.c>
      FilterDeclare   COMPRESS
      FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE "%{Content_Type} = 'text/html'"
      FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE "%{Content_Type} = 'text/css'"
      FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE "%{Content_Type} = 'text/plain'"
      FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE "%{Content_Type} = 'text/xml'"
      FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE "%{Content_Type} = 'text/x-component'"
      FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE "%{Content_Type} = 'application/javascript'"
      FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE "%{Content_Type} = 'application/json'"
      FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE "%{Content_Type} = 'application/xml'"
      FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE "%{Content_Type} = 'application/xhtml+xml'"
      FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE "%{Content_Type} = 'application/rss+xml'"
      FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE "%{Content_Type} = 'application/atom+xml'"
      FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE "%{Content_Type} = 'application/vnd.ms-fontobject'"
      FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE "%{Content_Type} = 'image/svg+xml'"
      FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE "%{Content_Type} = 'image/x-icon'"
      FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE "%{Content_Type} = 'application/x-font-ttf'"
      FilterProvider  COMPRESS  DEFLATE "%{Content_Type} = 'font/opentype'"
      FilterChain     COMPRESS
      FilterProtocol  COMPRESS  DEFLATE change=yes;byteranges=no
   </IfModule>
   <IfModule !mod_filter.c>
      # Legacy versions of Apache
      AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/css application/json
      AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
      AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml application/xml text/x-component
      AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml application/rss+xml application/atom+xml
      AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml application/vnd.ms-fontobject application/x-font-ttf font/opentype
   </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

I am expecting the `encode-content: gzip` header in response for request: `example.com/test.js`, but I do not see it.

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean?

Comment: I don't see the `encode-content: gzip` header in response for request: http://example.com/test.js